# Hungarian Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix, hungarian-algorithm

I've implemented hungarian algorithm in C. It works well, in most of the cases.
From time to time it just so happens that my code cannot find the solution for some matrices. Checking solution I'm starting to think that how matrix is covered matters. Here's an example:

this is the matrix when first two steps are executed(subtract min for each row, and min for each col

```
7  65  0   90   0  90
8  33  49  16  41   0
0   0  63  45  46  69
62 72  50   6  39   0 
62  6  54   0   2  42
 7  1  49  19   0  58
```

when covered using my code (2 meaning element is crossed 2 times):

```
1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1
```

I looked for solution [here](http://www.hungarianalgorithm.com/solve.php?c=18-74-9-99-9-99--55-78-94-61-86-45--10-8-71-53-54-77--91-99-77-33-66-27--85-27-75-21-23-63--49-41-89-59-40-98) using same original matrix and they covered matrix differently. Instead of selecting last two columns, they selected last two rows. With two more matrix reduction they end up with matching. I, on the other hand don't.

Is there some way of deciding which line combination is better?